# When to use functional update form of useState() hook, eg. setX(x=>x+1)

Tags: javascript, reactjs, react-hooks, updates, setstate

Normally when we need to update a state in a functional component, we do something like this:

```
function Example() {
    const [count, setCount] = React.useState(0);
    return (<div><p>You clicked {count} times</p>
                 <button onClick={() => setCount(count + 1)}>
                    Click me
                 </button>
            </div>);
}
```

When and why will we ever need to use the functional update form?

```
function Example() {
    const [count, setCount] = React.useState(0);
    return (<div><p>You clicked {count} times</p>
                 <button onClick={() => setCount(c=>c + 1)}>
                    Click me
                 </button>
            </div>);
}
```

Comment: When you know that `newState` is dependent on the `previous` state. Simple

Comment: @DecPK Is it safe to say that for operations such as incrementing the state variable by `x`, we should always do `setState(count => count + 1)` instead of `setState(count+1)`

Comment: @Murtuza Not necessary when you are using functional update you will get the latest value at that time. and when you use just `count + 1` then `count` will be taken from closure.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Use the function form when the setter may close over an old state value.

For example, if an async request is initiated, and you want to update state after that's done, the request that was made will have scope of the state as it was at the beginning of the request, which may not be the same as the most up-to-date render state.

You may also need to use the function form if the same state value was *just* updated, eg

```
setValue(value + 1);
// complicated logic here
if (someCondition) {
  setValue(value => value + 1);
}
```

because the second call of `setValue` closes over an old `value`.

Comment: I tried calling setCount(x=>(x+1)) twice in a row but it still incremented by 1 only.

Comment: @ChongLipPhang That should not happen. It should increment by two.

Answer (score 1):

State Updates May Be Asynchronous:

https://reactjs.org/docs/state-and-lifecycle.html#state-updates-may-be-asynchronous

`useState` is the same as setState in this condition.

Answer (score 1):

You can see the different when call set state twice:

```
<button
  onClick={() => {
    setCount(count + 1);
    setCount(count + 1);
  }}
></button>;

<button
  onClick={() => {
    setCount(c => (c + 1));
    setCount(c => (c + 1));
  }}
></button>;
```

Comment: Can we say that the functional update form is synchronous?

Comment: No. functional update always get newest value of stae

Answer (score 1):

There are other use cases too. For example, when you call `useState` inside an effect. If new state is dependent on old state, this might cause an infinite loop.

```
useEffect(() => {
  setCounter(counter + 1);
}, [counter]);
```

You can avoid this by using functional updates:

```
useEffect(() => {
  setCounter(old => old + 1);
}, []);
```

Comment: I wish I can undo the upvote... Doesn't useEffect(() => {setCounter(counter+ 1);}, []); achieve the same thing?

Comment: @ChongLipPhang removing a dependency from deps array is against react-hooks linting rules (`exhaustive-deps`). Also, it won't update `counter` correctly. This is just a basic example. There are more complicated, real-world cases when you should update states in `useEffect` hooks.

Answer (score 1):

The functional update form also allows the update function to be passed to its children while still having access to the parent’s state.

```
function MyButton(props){
     // return <button onClick={()=>props.onClick(count+1)}>+1</button>;  // error as count is not exposed here
     return <button onClick={()=>props.onClick(n=>(n+1))}>+1</button>;
}
function Example() {
   const [count, setCount] = React.useState(0);
   return (<div><p>Counter: {count}</p>
                <MyButton onClick={setCount}/>
           </div>);
}
ReactDOM.render(<Example/>,document.querySelector("div"));
```

Answer (score 0):

According to this: https://reactjs.org/docs/state-and-lifecycle.html#state-updates-may-be-asynchronous

The `the functional update` form make sure that the previous state that you take reference from is the latest / finalized version when there might be multiple setState hook (which is asynchronous) called (for example, if the user spam click on the button)

And also due to its async nature, the state will not be updated right away within a function, for e.g:

```
func() {
 console.log(counter) // counter = 1
 setCounter(counter => counter + 1) // counter = 1
 console.log(counter) // counter = 1
}
```