# How to prevent useEffect from being called multiple times when there's a relationship between it's dependencies?

Tags: reactjs, react-hooks

Given a functional React component with a local function `fn()` and numeric counters `a` and `b`:

```
const [a, setA] = useState(0);
const [b, setB] = useState(0);

function fn() { console.log(a, b); }
```

Where the function `fn()` is called when `a` or `b` change:

```
useEffect(()=> { 
  fn();
}, [a, b]);
```

We'll have two buttons that increment `a` and `b` by 1.

```
<button onClick={()=> setA(a => a + 1)}>Increment A: {a}</button>
<button onClick={()=> setB(b => b + 1)}>Increment B: {b}</button>
```

but when `a` increments, we'll increment `b` as well:

```
useEffect(()=> {
  setB(b => b + 1);
}, [a]);
```

How do I make the `fn()` run only once when clicking on "Increment A" and not react to both changes individually? The rendering pass that updates `a` state variable causes `b` to change, which will cause another render pass. How can I prevent this and make it happen in one pass?

Edit:

Addition #1: `b` doesn't have to change always, so let's say that this `useEffect` resets `b` to 0.

```
useEffect(()=> {
  setB(0);
}, [a]);
```

Addition #2: Let's change `a` not to be a local state variable, but an input prop, which changes outside of the scope of this component.

Comment: What about combining both state variables into a single state, e.g. useState({ a: 0, b: 0 })? Would that setup work in your case?

Comment: I guess I simplified my use case too much:). What if `a` would be a prop and `b` a local state variable?

Answer (score 1):

If, when `a` always changes, `b` changes too, then it's simple - just change the dependency array to be only `[b]`. If the first changes comes from `a`, `fn` will run after the `[b]` effect. If the first change comes from `b`, `fn` will run just after the first re-render.

```
useEffect(()=> { 
  fn();
}, [b]);
```

---

Another approach that can reduce rerenderings in similar situations would be to exchange `setA` with another function that both sets `a` and runs `setB`. Instead of

```
const [a, setA] = useState(0);
const [b, setB] = useState(0);
useEffect(()=> {
  setB(b => b + 1);
}, [a]);
```

you can have

```
const [a, setAUnbound] = useState(0);
const [b, setB] = useState(0);
const setA = (newA) => {
  setAUnbound(newA);
  setB(b => b + 1);
};
```

and not reference `setAUnbound` again. This way, the functionality of what was previously in the effect is now baked into the state setter function. (I usually like this sort of approach more than using `useEffect`. It not only makes things feel a bit cleaner, it also prevents linters from complaining about `exhaustive-deps`)

Now you can call `setA` like you would any state setter without a callback.

```
<button onClick={()=> setA(a + 1)}>Increment A: {a}</button>
```

Using callbacks to set state [isn't necessary here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/68797262), but if you were in a situation where it was needed, you can check the `typeof` the `newA` argument to determine whether you need to call it or not.

---

If the situation is different and

> Let's say I on every change of `a` I would set `b` to 0. That would require both `a` and `b` to be in the dependency array. Also `a` could be an input prop and change outside of this component.

then one way to manage this would be to move the child's state into the parent and have the parent update everything at once (either by combining the two state variables into one, or by using the `setAUnbound` approach described above). Then the child component would only see one change and its effect would run just once.

Messier approaches exist, but the above are what I'd prefer.

Comment: shouldn't the setAUnbound be incrementing a? e.g. setAUnbound( a => a + 1)?

Comment: That would make it less generic and only allow single increments. Better to allow `setA` to be called with any argument like any state setter - so you'd do `setA(a + 1)`. If the callback form is needed, it can be done with a `typeof` check on the argument.

Comment: IMHO: It certainly sounds more flexible but deviates from the code in question which is about incrementing both values by +1. Perhaps, your last comment should be added as a sidenote and the code be updated to reflect the single increment required by the original code in the question. People looking for the answer will be confused at first, as there's no 1-to-1 correspendence with the original code.

Comment: The abstraction I chose here didn't account for the fact, that `b` doesn't have to change always. Let's say I on every change of `a` I would set `b` to 0. That would require both `a` and `b` to be in the dependency array. Also `a` could be an input prop and change outside of this component.